# Set up URL redirect for a localhost site

Tags: xampp, web-development-server

I've developed a small site for an academic project, and I'd like to have it being shown as a live site, with its own domain name.

For example: I want to enter the domain name JustAnExample.com, but it should access the localhost.

I've tried to change the Hosts file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Hosts file should work!

adding > 127.0.0.1 justanexample.com <

will redirect it to localhost.

this may help! [Editing local host file](https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/)

Comment: I tried every configuration I could think of, and it never worked.
I guess the old adage is true: it's always the one you don't try.
Thank you, Jan!